# Domain not redirected correctly with Wordpress Multisite

Tags: multisite, wp-config, site-url, domain-mapping, dns

My Wordpress multisite installation uses two sites:

```
Site 1: www.myexample.com
Site 2: blog.myexample.com
```

In addition, I own a second domain `myexample2.com`, which I would like to redirect to the subdomains of the original domain.

Here are its CNAME records in DNS settings:

```
; A Records
@   600  IN     A   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

; CNAME Records
blog    600  IN     CNAME   blog.myexample.com
www 600  IN     CNAME   www.myexample.com
```

The problem is that when calling `blog.myexample2.com` the home page `www.myexample.com` gets loaded instead of `blog.myexample.com`.

The problem seems to be in some Wordpress setting, `wp-config.php` may be causing this.

Part of `wp-config.php` related to Multisite:

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://www.myexample.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.myexample.com' );
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.myexample.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 2);

define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'https://www.myexample.com' );
```

Comment: have you created the site "blog.myexample2.com" in the network administration ?

Comment: Why would blog.myexample2.com load blog.myexample.com? It doesn't make sense

Comment: @Kaperto I have only created “blog.myexample.com” site in network administration. Calls to “blog.myexample2.com” should be redirected to that site.

Comment: @PeterGerhat domain redirects and domain mappings are 2 completely different things, can you edit your question to reflect that you meant redirecting, not mapping?

Comment: then try to set `NOBLOGREDIRECT` to `https://blog.myexample.com`

Comment: @Kaperto in that case I'm having the opposite problem, `www.myexample2.com` redirected to `blog.myexample.com`

Comment: then you need to set the blog and site in the special file "wp-content/sunrise.php". look in the file `wp-includes/ms-settings.php` to see what you have to define.

Comment: still don't know what needs to be changed the file, perhaps try to explain.